# Application settings does not contain location service

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I have an application which requires location access. If location service under settings->privacy in ON and I installed my application then location service will be available under my app settings even my app is listed under location services list. But when location service under settings->privacy is OFF and I installed my app, it will show the alert to turn ON location service in settings->privacy but my app is not listed under location services list, even in my app settings location service is not available to turn it ON/OFF.
Please let me know, if there any way to get location service in app settings or this is a bug with apple itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After so many times of reading your question, I finally got what you're trying to say. So I did the following:

- **Turned off** the Location Services in SETTINGS.

Result: Of course the list of the apps that uses location services became hidden.

- Installed a certain project that uses Location Services.

Result: The popup - "Turn On Location Services to Allow **"App_Name"** to Determine Your Location". It has two buttons: SETTINGS and CANCEL. I clicked the SETTINGS button.

- After being redirected to the Settings from Step 2, I turned on Location Services.

Result: The settings listed again the apps that use Location Services. Including my newly installed project. I can turn on the location services in my app settings, or restart my app to produce a pop up that it needs me to allow it to access my location.

So, I'm guessing you need to add these keys to your info.plist.

**NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** - value: "APP_NAME" needs your location"

and

**NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** - value: "APP_NAME" needs your location"

I've written a quite 'nasty' tutorial for [MKMapView Implementing Programmatically](http://www.prettyitgirl.com/2016/03/implementing-mkmapview-programmatically.html). It includes the info.plist that I mentioned and catching the current location services state.

Comment: "Result: The settings listed again the apps that use Location Services. Including my newly installed project. I can turn on the location services in my app settings, or restart my app to produce a pop up that it needs me to allow it to access my location." In my case app does not appear under  location service. I have already set those two keys in info.plist.

Comment: read the latter part of my answer. Have you set the two keys I mentioned in your info.plist?